# How do the Star Trek com badges stay attached?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-ds9

Several times, in several episodes throughout all of the series, there's a time when someone just rips off their comm badge, or they put one on. There's no pin on it, and it's a seemingly flawless transition of "I put the badge on and it stays." Is it explained anywhere how these stay on with little effort to put them on?

**EDIT**

I'd like to see an in-universe answer more, but as stated, I think both in and out would be interesting.

Comment: Due to the ambiguity; Could you clarify if you are looking for an in-universe or an out-of-universe answer? (I believe both would be interesting).

Comment: @bitmask: I made the edit. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'd guess some kind of futuristic alternative to Velcro.

Comment: Memory Alpha is mum on the topic, interestingly enough: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Combadge

Comment: In DS9 "Past Tense", Dax is wearing 2024-manufactured clothing which looks like a regular (as 1990s imagined it) suit, but her badge stays on it.  She'd have had to make a special effort to achieve that (e.g. special glue instead of e.g. keep it in her pocket) if the below "it's the magnetic uniform" answers are right.  Also, in some episodes Jake is wearing civilian clothes and sticks a badge on without prior warning.  So tenuously,   it's more like "a badge sticks to any clothing if you activate that" (since they don't appear to stick to random things), but without any real explanation how.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From http://star-trek.answers.wikia.com/wiki/How_are_combadges_and_rank_pips_attached_to_the_uniform:

> They are attached magnetically. The fabric of their uniforms has metallic properties, even though they are not actually metallic. They "resemble" it as far as the physics of the com badges are concerned.
>
> **In the *Star Fleet Technical Manual* (1973), it was referred to as "magnatomic adhesion"**

(note: SFTM is not canon but pretty authoritative).

---

For another non-canon but "authoritative" source, we have [GURPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GURPS): *(TREK - THE UNAUTHORIZED SOURCEBOOK*, 2d edition)*

> **COMMUNICATORS**: ...  Comm badges can adhere to almost any surface using a magnatomic adhesion area. ... (SECTION 2F - "TREK TECH" - Part 6 - Miscellaneous)

Comment: Someone with that affinity for orthography is doubtful as a source of information. Especially when we have to take solely their word for it.

Comment: @bitmask - they are quoting SFTM which is AFAIK an authoritative resource.

Comment: Sounds more like recollection, not a literal quote from SFTM (otherwise, I'd begin to worry about SFTM). So, without further evidence we have to take their word that this information is genuine (which, to be fair, has nothing to do with spelling and grammar).

Comment: @bitmask - the use of the term by SFTM can be cross-checked from a couple of other sources: https://www.google.com/search?q=magnatomic+adhesion so it's not a Wikia writers invention.

Comment: Corroborating that with other sources constitutes an answer. +2

Comment: @bitmask There's another question on here about how phasers stayed on in TOS, and the in-universe explanation was the same, IIRC

Comment: @DVK: One of my first thoughts was that they were "magnetic" for cloth. There always seemed to be a "chirp" when they were put on, indicating it was on. Thanks. Happen to have an out of universe answer as well?

Comment: @DVK: That makes me sad panda. But thank you for the answers.

Comment: Just to clarify: "Magnatomic" is treknobabble and shouldn't be taken to mean "magnetic". There have been times when a commbadge has been stuck to something other than a starfleet uniform. I can think of think of no canonical explanation of the method of adhesion. It's just some sort of futuristic adhesive. Note though, that it is most likely necessary that either it only sticks to fabric, or pressure must be applied in order for the adhesive to work. Several episodes in the various TNG-era series have shown someone placing a badge on a table, or picking one up from a table, without having to "

Comment: "Magnets...ALWAYS with the magnets..."

Answer (score 1):

### out of universe

FWIW, I figured it was magnetic from remembering Data remove his to use as a bet in a poker game when he as stranded in the past.  I duplicated it by using Gaf Tape to attach the metal plate to the inside of the ordinary cloth costume.  Just clasping it with the plate on the inside (magnet molded into the resin prop) would allow it to fall out if the badge were removed in a scene, or accidently bumped.

(Note: in that scene it did not stick to the table. It appears to home in to the right spot when attached.)

However, mine twists along an axis directly over the magnet. The series production must have used multiple magnets or a rough prickly texture on the backside which was never seen.  More likely used pins when the badge was not needed to be removed or attached during the scene: at least after season 2 when shirts were made of normal cloth and were not form-fitting.  I never determined how it was done on the spandix uniform: pins or double-stick tape would not work well or even damage the material. So I suppose a thin metal plate that fit (only) behind the badge, and was anti-swivil, was designed to go with the original S1/S2 uniforms.  Adding a little tape would permit the apply-or-remove actions we saw.

### in universe + hard SF

Rather than a crude ferromagnetic plate as a bulk piece, a patch meant to accept the badge would be fabricated into the cloth. It would be no more mysterious to them than post-it notes are to us.

One time I marvelled at a label attached to a non-stick pan. It was quite strong to peel off but only barely tacky to feel or against ordinary surfaces. I thought the sticky had been spent, and was surprized that it still stuck *strongly* to teflon.

Clearly you can design to materials to be sticky (only) to each other.  Patches of A in an aligned grid would allow B to stick in the intended spot and easily be positioned straight.

Using "molecules" (purpose-specific adhesive) would better fit the stated references, and has advangages advantages over magnets around equipment and in strange conditions.