# Out-of-universe, how are Star Trek combadges attached?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, behind-the-scenes, communication, star-trek-uniforms

[image]

How are combadges attached?

(Is there any reference in-universe to how they stay on? [This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39635/how-do-the-star-trek-com-badges-stay-attached) primarily focuses on in-universe explanation  -- there is a mention of out-of-universe in an answer, but it's very weak)

Out of universe, how are the props they attached?   (Magnets, velcro, pins?)

Presuming the answer is different, how are they attached temporarily in scenes where the combadge is donned or doffed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Out of universe, they were attached using **velcro** or **pins**, or sometimes **magnetically** in scenes where they were donned or doffed. [Here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Talk:Combadge) is a discussion of the issue:

> It's never stated in 'canon' how it is done, but for costuming, they are attached with velcro as shown through the [It's A Wrap! sale and auction](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/It%27s_A_Wrap!_sale_and_auction). :)

> I even once read that they had two versions, one velcro-attached and another attached with a strong magnet - you can see the latter in the DS9 episode where Dax meets his/her former love and Sisko brings her upside down badge into the right position on the dress uniform again. They used the velcro version most of the time when the combadge didn't have to be removed for script reasons.

Following the link to the sale and auction, and then a [few](http://startrekpropcollector.com/trekauctions/) more [links](http://startrekpropcollector.com/trekauctions/page.pl?p=iaw/allitems.html) beyond that, I found item descriptions for several of the combadges sold there:

- [one](http://startrekpropcollector.com/trekauctions/item.pl?i=0460) with "a Velcro patch on the back"
- [one](http://startrekpropcollector.com/trekauctions/item.pl?i=0464), [two](http://startrekpropcollector.com/trekauctions/item.pl?i=6688), [three](http://startrekpropcollector.com/trekauctions/item.pl?i=7168) with "an adhered Velcro placement for a corresponding one affixed to almost any uniform"
- [one](http://startrekpropcollector.com/trekauctions/item.pl?i=5437) with "no Velcro placement" but "pin backing for bending over into fabric"
- [one](http://startrekpropcollector.com/trekauctions/item.pl?i=5933) "with Velcro backing"
- [one](http://startrekpropcollector.com/trekauctions/item.pl?i=6167) with "the reverse [...] hollowed out to allow a cavity for a Velcro placement"
- [one](http://startrekpropcollector.com/trekauctions/item.pl?i=6288) with "a Velcro placement on the reverse"
- [one](http://startrekpropcollector.com/trekauctions/item.pl?i=6599) with " four pins that have lost a degree of their fastening quality, a three pin placement and a single pin placement that push through the collar of the undershirt"
- [one](http://startrekpropcollector.com/trekauctions/item.pl?i=6749) with "a Velcro placement"

These props span many different seasons of Star Trek.

[Here](http://www.trekbbs.com/showthread.php?t=182312) is a more detailed but also more speculative answer, in which pins, velcro, and various ways of using magnets are discussed. It makes for an interesting read, but the above quotes seem to be more definite. The top post [here](http://www.trekbbs.com/showthread.php?t=214690) also says the answer is magnets and velcro.

---

In-universe, they are attached **magnetically**. From [Star Trek Answers Wikia](http://star-trek.answers.wikia.com/wiki/How_are_combadges_and_rank_pips_attached_to_the_uniform):

> They are done magnetically. The fabric has metallic properties that they where [sic]. Even though the uniforms are not actually metallic. They "resemble" it as far as teh [sic] physics of the com badges are concerned.

> In the Star Fleet Technical Manual (1973), it was referred to as "magnatomic adhesion"

> And in the DS9 episode where Worf appeared, a metal strip on the side of the collar is seen (on the inside of where the pips go on the outside). Presumably something similar for the combadges? Although I have no clue how they seem to be able to stick onto any clothing. Probably best not to think about it (after all, it's just velcro in real life)

Comment: For the record, the badges seen in the 1973 technical manual are not com-badges. They're just badges

Comment: This is all still pretty weak hearsay.   I feel like there should be some better info out there.   (Also, BTW, I don't think that 'It's a Wrap' link is good anymore -- I don't see any reference to 'com', 'badge' or 'velcro')

Comment: @ThePopMachine Check again! :-) I followed the 'It's a Wrap' link and found a whole _mine_ of information.

Comment: If you'll allow me to rant: in-universe, is there really any reason they couldn't just be attached with a good old fashioned pin? Did Star Trek really need to come up with an advanced, futuristic way to attach something to a shirt when we've had perfectly functioning technology for a millennium?

Comment: @TenthJustice:   In universe, we know that can attach and detach without a pin.   We see it all the time.   They just put it on or take it off whenever they want.

Comment: @randal'thor:   Maybe I'm a dummy. Can you be a little more explicit about how the link you gave gets us to the info you quoted?

Comment: @ThePopMachine The link is down the page, under "External links." *(I'm not a fan of mystery on Q&A sites. I prefer info.)*

Comment: @ThePopMachine I added a couple more links to make my path clearer.

Comment: @Richard The badges aren't detailed in the 1973 technical manual, but I agree that there was nothing in it (or TOS in general) to indicate that they were anything but insignia patches, anyway.  In the manual, the phasers and communicators are shown as having 'magnatomic adhesion' areas on them.  On the type II (handgun-style) phaser, it was on the grip.

Comment: It seems like I remember there being a "electrostatic" reason given in the 1990's TNG Tech Manual, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @TenthJustice why do we use velcro/zippers in real life when buttons/laces work just fine?

Comment: @TenthJustice Geckos' microscopic foot hairs use van der waals forces to stick to things.  Babylon 5's hand badges "in-universe" basically use that to stick to skin.  TNG in-universe sound a little more magnetic but regardless - In the 24th century it is just a easy to manufacture a universal sticky surface as it is a pin.